# How to play XBMC media on a mac

Tags: macos, upnp, xbmc

I have a small linux box hosting openELEC, XBMC (Frodo), and I want to play its media on my mac. I cannot seem to find any clients suitable for playing the content. Is anyone familiar with a piece of software capable of streaming media from my uPnP media server?

Thanks!

Comment: XBMC runs on the Mac too.

Comment: It does, but to the best of my knowledge, it requires a centralized database to store the library information, that openELEC is incapable of running. Hence, I need just ANY piece of software that can 1. Run on a mac and 2. Play media from a uPnP source.

Comment: * That is to run two instances of XBMC and have their media synchronized.

Comment: XBMC can play from a uPnP server... from "Videos | Add Files" you can select "Add Videos...", then "Browse", then "UPnP Devices".  The procedure for Music is similar.

Comment: BTW, it's not a great solution for a desktop as you'll need to remember some keyboard commands, but the only other way I've found is file sharing + a "normal" media player.  If you find anything better, let us know :-).